# How to differentiate a collection versus a single object through reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have this:

```
var Virtual = Property.GetValue(Entity, null);
```

Entity is being pulled from a repository using Entity Framework.

How can I determine if it is a single object, or a collection?

I tried checking the type, but wasn't sure what to compare it to.

```
var VirtualType = Virtual.GetType();
```

Upon inspection with a debugger, Virtual is either a `DynamicProxy` of an instantiated single `class`, or a `HashSet` of an instantiated `ICollection`. If `.GetType()` is used on the `DynamicProxy` this is thrown:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I also tried this:

```
var test = (IEnumerable<object>)Virtual;
if (test.Count() > 0)
```

which works on the collection, but fails on the single object.

I also tried this:

```
if (Virtual is Enumerable)
```

but it was false, even for the collection.

How can I discern the two through reflection?

Comment: `Enumerable` is a static class - you want `if (Virtual is IEnumerable)`

Comment: did you try testing Virtual is IEnumerable. IEnumerable would be the common denominator for both generic and non-generic Collection, Enumerations etc. Keep in mind though, that string implements IEnumerable too, but probably should not be treated as a collection.

Comment: @Lee - Thanks, this did in fact work without throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a quick guess from looking at your code.

```
//works for collection but throws exception for single object (as it should)
var test = (IEnumerable<object>)Virtual;

//try using
var test = Virtual as IEnumerable;
if(test == null) // single object
```

this is the same as

```
if(Virtual is IEnumerable){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if it implements `IEnumerable`:

```
if (Virtual is IEnumerable)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: this assumes that every EF collection inherits from `ICollection` because regular `IEnumerable<>` doesn't, but +1 anywyay.

Comment: @StanR. I changed it to check for `IEnumerable` which should work since `ICollection` itself inherits from `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

[`Type.IsAssignableFrom()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is a very useful method for determining what assignments a type supports:

```
if (VirtualType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ICollection)) {
  // Do something
}
```